# Encrypting text file line by line with stable encryption

Tags: reference-request, file-encryption

I want to store files in a secure manner (i.e. no one should be able to decrypt the contents of the file without the secret key) but I also want a diff tool to be able to show me which lines changed (let's assume that you can't learn anything about the content of the file by seeing which lines have changed).

The idea is to encrypt each line individually and convert the result to hex or BASE64 and then write each line into one file. A line with a certain content should always return the same output, no matter where it is in the file.

Specifically, I want a version control tool like Git or Mercurial to be able to efficiently handle the files as text. At the same time, a (self written) UI should be able to show a decrypted diff without the need of decrypting the data inside of the version control tool (`git diff` would show me the line numbers which I could then decrypt in my app to display them myself).

Is that possible? Do you know where I can find more information how to do this?

Comment: Yes, what you suggest is possible. Are you after suggestions for which algorithms to choose or after a practical implementation? The latter is off topic for this site.

Comment: I first need some pointers how to get started: Suggestions for algorithms which are well suited for this purpose and things like that so I can start asking implementation questions on SO without getting downvoted.

Comment: AES-SIV - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5297 - is an appropriate algorithm to use in this case.

Comment: @louism: That sounds very promising but I couldn't find any information about the actual implementation. The link just gives an overview (unlike other RFCs).

Comment: Check out https://github.com/cryodex/siv-rb for a Ruby extension, which wraps around a C implementation by Dan Harkins.

Comment: @louism: Thanks. I'll use that as a guideline - I'm hesitant to use code which contains comments like "For some reason, weird things happen when when `zero` is global"; well, the array is written to from several functions, so they get in each other's way. Nothing weird about it.

Comment: This is actually a modification of the code by jacobsa: https://github.com/jacobsa/crypto. I didn't bother taking out the added comments, but you are right about why that error was happening in the original code (which is now fixed). Obviously this is not "production-ready" code, but it will get you far enough in terms of understanding the mechanics of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Encrypting each line independently, like you suggest is the way to go.

Most likely you will want to use a symmetric encryption algorithm independently for each line – i.e. have a new unique IV/nonce per line. That's the simplest to implement. However, it means every line is up to 128 bits longer. If you can't live with that, you practically have to either sacrifice some security (e.g. use [ECB mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) without [semantic security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security)) or have changes to one line affect nearby lines as well.

One question to consider is whether to use authenticated encryption to guard against an attacker being able to modify the file. This is usually the way to go, but if you have something that ensures integrity at a higher level in your setup (signed tags/commits, say), you could afford to skip it.

For authenticated encryption you need to further decide whether you want a single MAC for the whole file (slower, since it needs to be recalculated after every modification) or one per line (which takes even more space).

---

In practice, I would go with AES for encryption. (Either 128-bit or 256-bit keys – [doesn't matter much](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5118/13625) in practice.)

1. If you can live with the extra space it requires, the absolute simplest from an implementation standpoint (when you have a library that supports it), is to use AES in [GCM mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode). You get both encryption and authentication in one, and the only requirement for IVs is uniqueness. Each line will be up to 256 bits longer (when using 128 bits for both IV and auth. tag).
2. If you have authentication already, I would go with AES [CTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29). If you know the file will never have more that $2^k$ lines through its lifetime (counting each version of each line) you could store a $k$-bit value per line instead of a full 128-bit IV. You *will* need to make sure you never reuse a counter value in any case, including different "forks" of the file.
3. If you need a MAC for the file, you can do the above and append an HMAC.

Comment: That sounds like I should save the IV/nonce along with the line data. Otherwise, how would I get the same value again when I encode the lines a second time? My gut feeling is that creating the IV/nonce from the line content is a bad idea, right?

Comment: Ah, I just realized you answered the "save IV with line" part in point #1 above.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, exactly. You can't really derive it from the line content because you don't know the content before decrypting. (Also because that would lead to collisions on equal lines.)

Comment: Thanks. As for the k-bit value in #2 above: Can I use a plain counter for this? Or does it have to be random?

Comment: @AaronDigulla, a counter is fine, the same values can just never repeat for the same key.

Comment: Here is the link for CTR mode: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29

Comment: I think most of us know CTR mode, it is actually part of GCM mode encryption :) Note that there is a problem. If line 1 moves to line 2, then the ciphertext would be entirely different (apart from the size). This would play hell with `diff`. But if you use a mode without IV (**not CTR**), you can see duplicates in the code. And either way, you leak info about the line size. So you have to make some choices if you use this solution.

Comment: @owlstead: Not everyone visiting this site knows as much about encryption as people who hang around here, so adding links often helps.

Comment: Right you are Aaron. Removed comment and downvote. But I think there are still issues with this approach. You would probably need to decrypt to see which lines have changed, then reencrypt the same lines with the original nonce. This will also leak information (obviously).

Answer (score 2):

You may be better off encrypting the file using normal file encryption, and then encrypting the diff that goes with the file, *except* for the line numbers included in the diff. You could also extract the line number changes from the diff in advance. Otherwise you will have to keep track of the lines, and make sure that the nonces used for each line stay identical.

Also, due to the nature of encryption/decryption, small changes (e.g. to indentation) will result in huge changes in the ciphertext. Even if you use something like CTR mode encryption, you will have to reencrypt changed lines with a different nonce.

Regardless, you will of course convey a lot of information about the plaintext, but that's more or less inherent if you want to perform diffs on the ciphertext.

---

All in all, this could be harder than you might imagine at first glance.

Comment: I don't think I have the time or energy to change the source code of Git or Mercurial. But maybe a better solution would be to hook into Mercurial and encrypt the changesets themselves.

Comment: If you can get away with encryption on a higher level (e.g. the entire DB) than that would be *much* easier to implement. But yeah, that depends on the use case and attack scenarios.

Comment: I have plain text files and I need an efficient way to preserve the edit history. So encoding individual lines currently looks like the way to go since then, I can use the standard tool chain for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

*"Specifically, I want a version control tool like Git or Mercurial to be able to efficiently handle the files
...
I need an efficient way to preserve the edit history."*

The [rsyncrypto](http://rsyncrypto.lingnu.com/index.php/Home_Page) tool can help version control tools efficiently handle small changes to files, but in bigger chunks than one-line-at-a-time.
The rsyncrypto is designed to encrypt files (using standards such as AES encryption as much as possible)
such that

> two almost identical files, such as the same file before an after a
>   change, when encrypted using rsyncrypto and the same key, will produce
>   almost identical encrypted files.

When you temporarily decrypt a file, change a few bytes, and then re-encrypt a file,
Git or Mercurial will see:

- without encryption: a few bytes of changes
- with the proposed line-by-line encryption: a few lines of changes
- with rsyncrypto: a few kbytes of changes
- with most other good encryption tools: pretty much the entire file is different

Perhaps rsyncrypto is close enough that you could use it as-is,
or perhaps you could use it with a small amount of tweaking.